# Does Extended WPF Toolkit propertygrid support Typeconverter attributes

Tags: c#, wpf, propertygrid

I have a typeconverter attribute on a class property. The typeconverter's `CanConvertFrom` and `CanConvertTo` are called several times, each time returning true, but `ConvertTo` and `ConvertFrom` never get called?

I'm trying to do exactly this, but then in WPF:
[Integers As Hex In The PropertyGrid (C# .NET)](http://koniosis.blogspot.nl/2009/02/integers-as-hex-in-propertygrid-c-net.html)

thank you,
Jef

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't look like it. I'm trying to use the `Description` attribute of enum values to display in an Extended WPF Toolkit `PropertyGrid`, which also uses `TypeConverter`. It works perfectly in WinForms but not in WPF, where there is no built-in `PropertyGrid`.